# DeSerializing a byte stream into an Java Class

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have nested "C" language data structures like this:

```
struct xyz {
  char a[256];
  char b[1024];
} XYZ;

struct abc {
  unsigned char dat1[1024];
  int dat2;
} ABC;

struct def {
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
} DEF;

struct tot {
  XYZ p1;
  ABC p2[45];
  DEF p3[17];
} TOT;

TOT tot;
```

After populating TOT, i write it to a file like this in the C program.

fwrite((char *)&tot,1,sizeof(TOT),file);

Now I have to read that same file back using a JAVA program, and re-create the same C data structures as corresponding JAVA classes for ANDROID.

So I make classes that look like the C structures above, those classes just contain the data members and no methods like this

```
class XYZ {
  byte a[]=new byte[256];
  byte b[]=new byte[1024];
} XYZ;

class ABC {
  byte dat1[1024];
  int dat2;
};

class DEF {
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
};

class TOT {
  XYZ p1;
  ABC p2[45];
  DEF p3[17];
};
```

I know there is some syntax error in the classes above but i hope you get the idea.

So how can I read all the bytes from the file and use that to create all these nested JAVA class objects as you see above to match the original C structures at the top?

I guess its like a de-serialization in JAVA (Android), but the serializer was a C program using fwrite.

It would be so hard to read the bytes one by one from the file, and fill in the JAVA class objects manually, and also while taking account for the different sizes of the data types and byte orders from Windows C to JAVA, is there a faster way?

Unfortunately the binary data is already written to the file using C and cant be changed, so I have to write a JAVA program to get it back and make those class objects from it.

thanks very much for any ideas!

Comment: Bad choice of a serialiser. Use a proper one which generates a platform-independent format. C does not enforce a specific layout on such structures beyond some very basic requirements.

Comment: Yes true, its not platform independent, but its very hard to change the file format at the moment.

Comment: How do i make proper platform independent serializer in C that can be deserialized in JAVA to recreate the nested JAVA classes?

Comment: That question is far off-topic here. This is no tutorial site. Said than, how about doing some research on your own? Just ignore the ones with casting, unions or `memcpy`, they mostly invoke undefined behaviour or have the same problems your's had. Look for those with bitshifts and which serialise the `struct`s member-wise.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easily with a `DataInputStream`, *provided* the sender is using network byte order.

If it isn't, I can only suggest that you throw the C end away and start again with a properly defined application protocol. As I keep saying here, 'don't use `structs` as application protocols. Use application protocols as application protocols'. You could look at XDR for example.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Olaf and EJP, where is the XDR example?

Comment: I repeat. **You** could look at XDR *for example.*

Comment: As I understand the question, the format is completely implementation specific. Neither endianess nor padding or encoding are actually fixed. But your suggestion is good. Just it does not matter which protocol to use, though, as long as it is well defined.

Comment: @Olaf I don't understand what point you are making in relation to my answer. You seem to be just agreeing with it, albeit in a strange way. The XDR wire format is completely specified in [RFC 4506](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4506).

Comment: The first part is a bit unclear. It seems to imply it is only a matter of endianess, ignoring the other pitfalls. Yes, the second part elaborates a bit, but imo it is not clear to the lazy reader they apply to the `struct`s in the question. Re the protocol recommendation: it is just that there is no need to use XDR, but any protocol will actually do. IMO protocol and exchange-format design/choice is one of the most underestimated issues when designing communication software (or storing data to a file).

Comment: @Olaf My answer consists almost in its entirety of a recommendation to use a defined protocol. I haven't said that network byte order is both necessary and sufficient to use `DataInputStream`, or stated any need to use XDR. I really decline to argue with you about statements I haven't made.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to load those structures into memory is the use of `ByteBuffer`, since you can control the endian order.

The following example will load the entire file into memory first, before build the Java objects. Since the Java objects will take even more memory than that, it shouldn't be a major problem.

The fields of the classes have been corrected too.

The code *assumes* little-endian order (x86 processor) and that the C `int` was 4 bytes, i.e. mapping to a Java `int`.

```java
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:/fileFromC.bin")));
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); // if C code was run on x86 processor
TOT tot = TOT.load(buffer);
```

```java
class XYZ {
    byte a[] = new byte[256];
    byte b[] = new byte[1024];
    static XYZ load(ByteBuffer buffer) {
        XYZ xyz = new XYZ();
        buffer.get(xyz.a);
        buffer.get(xyz.b);
        return xyz;
    }
}
```

```java
class ABC {
    byte[] dat1 = new byte[1024];
    int dat2;
    static ABC load(ByteBuffer buffer) {
        ABC abc = new ABC();
        buffer.get(abc.dat1);
        abc.dat2 = buffer.getInt();
        return abc;
    }
}
```

```java
class DEF {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    static DEF load(ByteBuffer buffer) {
        DEF def = new DEF();
        def.x = buffer.getInt();
        def.y = buffer.getInt();
        def.z = buffer.getInt();
        return def;
    }
}
```

```java
class TOT {
    XYZ p1;
    ABC[] p2 = new ABC[45];
    DEF[] p3 = new DEF[17];
    static TOT load(ByteBuffer buffer) {
        TOT tot = new TOT();
        tot.p1 = XYZ.load(buffer);
        for (int i = 0; i < tot.p2.length; i++)
            tot.p2[i] = ABC.load(buffer);
        for (int i = 0; i < tot.p3.length; i++)
            tot.p3[i] = DEF.load(buffer);
        return tot;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Java, but how do you guarantee identical encoidng, endianess and padding? Let along trhe widths of the data types. which can differ. C does not enforce a specific width for e.g. `int`, nor `char`.

Comment: @Olaf The 'guarantee' is in the hands of the programmer, of course. Endianness is specified by `buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)`, and `BIG_ENDIAN` is also available. Padding is implemented by `get()` for the padding bytes and throwing them away. Integer size is controlled by whether you call `getShort()`, `getInt()`, or `getLong()`.

Comment: @Olaf If you read the last paragraph of my answer, you'd see that I mentioned 2 assumptions about the encoding, i.e. endianness and size of `int`. You are right, I didn't mention padding, given that all the byte arrays have size that is a multiple of 4, so all ints are on 4-byte boundaries, and with no 8-byte members, so are the structs. Ergo, no padding anywhere.

Comment: Some architectures use 8 byte or even larger alignment for performance reasons (cache lines, internal busses, etc.), some none at all. I don't think your answer covers that sufficiently. That said from a C developer's view.

Comment: @EJP: AFAIK Java has 32 bit `int`s. C does not require that, so `getInt` is not necessarily what one needs. As your answer implies, the problem is on the C side by using implementation-specific formats which are not well documented and not portable (which is the worst). It is always a bad idea for a data exchange format to have the sink know about such details of the source.

Comment: Andreas - thanks so much for the code, I will certainly use it. Im new to Java and given this huge task to perform.

Comment: @Olaf You're right that not all platforms behave the same, hence the listed assumptions. Given the *"Unfortunately the binary data is already written to the file using C and cant be changed"* statement in the question, the encoding is already established for whatever platform they are using, and the code here can easily be modified if my assumptions were incorrect. I fail to understand your issue/objection, given the premise that their code is currently working for C code, so they obviously don't have mixed platforms.

Comment: @Andreas: OP's other comment raises some doubt the format is carved in stone.

Comment: @Olaf `getInt()` is not necessarily what one needs, *which is why I mentioned `getShort()` and `getLong()`*. You don't seem to be reading what is actually written here.